# Undergraduate-level book on modules, with emphasis on the structure theory of semisimple rings?

Tags: reference-request, modules, representation-theory

I am an undergraduate currently taking a representation theory course and we have $3$ chapters on modules, those being

- Basics (submodules, quotients, generators/relations, direct sums/products, tensor products)
- Finitely-generated modules over PIDs
- Semisimple modules (simple/semisimple modules, semisimple rings, Artin-Wedderburn)

For FG Modules over PIDs Jacobson's "Basic Algebra I" seems to be an adequate resource, but his coverage of semisimple rings/modules in II (using category theory and something called Morita contexts) is too high-brow for me. So far, I have found only $2$ other books: Robert Ash's online book on graduate algebra, which is a bit too terse and Weintraub's "Algebra", which on the other hand is a bit overlong and is overly concerned with projective modules and other things.

Is there any book/online resources you could recommend?

Comment: I do not recall Jacobson using category theory or Morita contexts to prove the Wedderburn theorem.  I don't think any book does: there are much more accessible expositions.  In fact I just flipped through it again, and it was as I thought: he covers the density theorem, and then deduces the Wedderburn theorem from that.

Comment: I don't have the book on me atm, but I remember the chapter on Morita contexts beginning with "We will prove the structure theorem for semisimple rings with [their] help" or something like that.

Answer (score 1):

> Bhattacharya, Phani Bhushan, Surender Kumar Jain, and S. R. Nagpaul. Basic abstract algebra. Cambridge University Press, 1994.

covers all these things at an undergraduate level.

Comment: A first glance at the contents seems to suggest that the authors use Noetherian/Artinian modules for deriving Artin-Wedderburn, while our course eschews that. Nevertheless, I'll check ot out more diligently later.

Comment: How could you possibly avoid talking about the descending chain condition? It's a key ingredient in the usual characterizations of semisimple rings.  Not mentioning the chain conditions would be a bit crazy to begin with.